# Javascript - Check values from one table and update another one

Tags: javascript, jquery

im a newbie in JS/jquery language and i need your help.
I have a table (table 1) with two columns, (results from a report).

I would like to create a function (jquery preferably) where i will check if the value of my id (from table 2) is equal to any value from the 1st column of  table 1 .If yes then i want the value from table 2 to be replaced by the value of the 2nd column from the same row of table 1 (looks like vlookup) .
I plan to read the values from table 1 with ajax(load method)

```js
function ApplyDate (){
 var elem,elem2,elem3,results;
 results = getIframeTableContent('reportresults2');//results in a table

 var arrayID =[94784115,89253812,54274389,90911418,93050321,84132668,120064524,107424636,120064713,120093751,119991064,115771514,100193238,102663072,116249190,112764322,111622229,106443644,119387007,120147215,120144800,119382025];

 for(var i=0;i<arrayID.length;i++){
  
  for(var k=0;k<results.length;k++){
   if(results[k][0] == arrayID[i]){
     
   elem2 = results[k][0];
   elem3 = results[k][1];
       if(document.getElementById(arrayID[i])) { 
     document.getElementById(arrayID[i]).innerHTML = elem3;
    }

   }
  }
 }
 
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Show us some code or what did you try?

Comment: When you say "tables" do you mean html tables or database tables?

Comment: I did something which is not efficient at all , in terms of maintenance .I want a completely different approach.I mean HTML tables

Comment: Can you please take a look at: http://jsfiddle.net/calinaadi/qejsvrew/ and then reply with a comment to see what you want to achieve.

Comment: @alipkok: see my demo source code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - demo: http://so.devilmaycode.it/javascript-check-values-from-one-table-and-update-another-one

```
var arrayID1 = [89253812, 94784115, 54274389, 90911418, 93050321, 120064524, 107424636, 120064713, 120093751, 119991064, 115771514, 100193238, 102663072, 116249190, 112764322, 111622229, 106443644, 119387007, 120147215, 120144800, 119382025, 84132668];
var arrayID2 = [94784115, 892538125, 542743893, 90911418, 93050321, 84132668, 120064524, 107424636, 120093751, 120064713, 1199941064, 1157715124, 1001932308, 1026603072, 116249190, 112764322, 1116222297, 1064436441, 1193870072, 120147214, 120144800, 119382025];
$(function() {
    $.each(arrayID1, function(i, item) {
        $('<tr><td>' + item + '</td><td> &mdash; ' + i + '</td></tr>').appendTo('#table-1');
    });
    $.each(arrayID2, function(i, item) {
        $('<tr><td>' + item + '</td><td> &mdash; ' + i + '</td></tr>').appendTo('#table-2');
    });
    $('#table-2 tr').each(function(i, item) {
        $("#table-1 tr:contains('" + $(this).find('td:eq(0)').text() + "')").find('td:eq(1)').css('color', 'green').text($(this).find('td:eq(1)').text());
    });
});
```

Comment: @alipkok: please, if the answer helped you check it.